# Swift iOS: How do I make an Instagram link?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview, swift2

In my app, I want to have an image view that shows the current Instagram profile picture of the account (and will automatically update if the picture is changed), and when this **image view is clicked, it links to the Instagram page.**

Is using a UIImageView the correct way to go about this?

I set up an UIImageView as so...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
       var bgImage: UIImageView?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Example")!
    bgImage = UIImageView(image: image)
    bgImage!.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,200)
    self.view.addSubview(bgImage!)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use Instagram API to keep it updated (https://instagram.com/developer/). Then request information from that API

```
func getInstagramProfileFromURLWithSuccess(success: ((instagramData: NSData!) -> Void)) {
    //1
    loadDataFromURL(NSURL(string: instagramURL)!, completion:{(data, error) -> Void in
        //2
        if error != nil {
            self.delegate.failedToRetriveData()
        }

        if let urlData = data {
            //3
            success(instagramData: urlData)
        }
    })
}
```

instagramURL should be like this "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/373368438?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_KEY"

You can take your userID from here http://jelled.com/instagram/lookup-user-id

Then parse the response using SwiftyJSON like this

```
self.getInstagramProfileFromURLWithSuccess { (data) -> Void in

        let json = JSON(data: data)

        let instagramArray = json["data"].arrayValue
        for dict in instagramArray {
             let profilePictureURL = dict["profile_picture"].stringValue

             //Send that URL to the imageView using a imageView that loads from url
        }
 }
```